# What is the first "stuck in a video game" type story?

Tags: history-of

I've recently started reading books that fall under a genre they are calling "LitRPG", and I noticed a lot of similarities to things like *.hack* and *Sword Art Online*. I remembered a lot of debate about which came first between those two, then I remembered *Captain N: The Game Master*. Granted it wasn't an MMO setting, but it was video game world.

So my question is, what is the first use of the "being stuck in a video game" trope as a story?

**EXCLUSIONS**

I'd like to state I would like to exclude the D&D cartoon, as that wasn't a video game. *TRON* might be close, as it is a "digital world", but in neither movie was he truly "stuck" in the game, as he could leave without consequence.

Comment: For this question, are you looking only for stories that involve a literal interpretation (e.g. real world characters grab a controller and get sucked in to a game) or would you allow a story where a real-world character interacts with any sort of game-mechanic (a portal, pipe, video-game-looking door, etc) and subsequently enters the game world?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the main character in _[Tron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron)_ (1982) was free to leave the simulation? The whole plot was driven by his quest to escape....

Comment: I wonder if Larry Niven and Steven Barnes' 1981 _[Dream Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Park)_ might fit the bill. Although there's no magical VR translation, characters do get stuck in a live-action RPG in a purpose-built theme park where things went wrong in a manner analogous to 1973's _[Westworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westworld_(film))_.

Comment: @Spencer - They weren't stuck in the LARP - they weren't extracted at the first sign of a problem, but I don't recall the tech going crazy enough that the game *couldn't* be stopped. However, I admit to having read *The Barsoom Project* quite recently, and I may be blocking something due to that.

Comment: I second Spencer’s question about *TRON*. The whole plot is that the MCP sees Flynn poking around and wants to do away with him, so he does the only thing he can do in the real world: uses the laser to digitize Flynn and trap him inside the system where he can be killed (aka “derezzed”). To quote the MCP: “Train him for the games, let him hope for a while, then blow him away.” The only way Flynn can get out is to take a specially encoded disc inside the MCP’s core to ride the communication beam out, which turns out to be very difficult.

Comment: @phyrfox: Looking for where the person was physically or mentally pulled into a video game world.

Comment: @Spencer: But they COULD escape, is why I was excluding it. Granted, I was thinking more of the recent TRON than the original. But even in the original, it wasn't really a "video game" so much as a "digital landscape".

Comment: A possibility may be Gillian Rubinstein's Space Demons which was published in 1985.

Comment: Ben Bova's The Dueling Machine (1969) might fit the bill